# Prostrate or Bowing Down

Tags: salat

Would it be incorrect to say “bowing down” instead of prostrate.

Mostly because it can be misunderstood as a male body part. And the word “bowing” is universally understood.

Or does this word need to be used for specificity. Similar to using the word precipitate instead of raining.

Comment: This is a question about english language rather than Islam. Prost**R**ate is different from Prostate. 'Bowing down' is ambiguous as it can mean ruku’ i.e. bowing one's back without putting one's face on the ground.